# How I can install the "linux-signed-lts-vivid package" security update?

Tags: software-installation, launchpad, patch, diff

I am an Ubuntu Trusty Tahr (14.04.3 LTS 64 Bit) user. In generally I do not know how to install "diffs" patches published in the Launchpad.net.

How can I install the security patch given in this page ( https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-signed-lts-vivid/3.19.0-28.30~14.04.1 ).

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: read `man patch`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to install the patch separately. You can just updated the package that is now in repositories already. Just run

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

and you will get the new kernel image with that patch.

You can also upgrade only this package by running

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-signed-image-generic
```

But that will upgrade only kernel image. Headers and some other packages may not be properly upgraded.

Comment: Thank you.  So, why they put the "Downloads" option  in there, for what reason?

Comment: This is for developers who want to apply this patch to some other code, etc.

Comment: Please recommend using "apt-get dist-upgrade", not "apt-get upgrade".  The latter won't install new packages, which is particularly unhelpful for kernel upgrades.

Comment: @ColinWatson I agree.

Comment: @SimkoSukak If you like the answer, just click the little grey **☑** at the left-hand side of the answer, now turning it into beautiful green. If you do not like the answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0, and if you *really* like the answer, click on the little grey checkmark *and* the little up-arrow... If you have any further questions, go to http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask **;)**